# Only allow double inputs with java scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Positive {
    public static void main (String args[]) {       
        double first;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter first value" + "\n");
        first= scan.nextDouble();

        if (first>0.00) {
            System.out.println("Please enter second value");
        }
        else if (first <0.00) {
            first =-first;
            System.out.println(first);
            System.out.println("Please enter second value");
        
        }
            
        double second;
        Scanner scaning = new Scanner(System.in);
        second = scan.nextDouble();
        if (first>second) {
            System.out.println(first-second);
        }
        else if (second>first) {
            System.out.println(second-first);
        }
    }
}
```

**Task:**
If the value is positive, request a second value. Print the difference between these two numbers so that the difference is always positive. For instance, if the first value is 10.3 and the second is 4.1, you would print the result of 6.2. If the first value is 3.8 and the second is 13.4 you would print the result 9.6.

> If the first value read is negative, print its positive equivalent. For instance, if its value is –89.6 you should print 89.6.
>
> If the first value is not a number, give appropriate error message (The standard error message from Java (e.g. “Exception in thread "main” ...”) does not count! Have a look at the Java API or Stack Overflow how to approach this).

The rest of the code runs correctly but I don't know how to only include double values in the input

Comment: What do you mean? You're using the `nextDouble` method to read input, so it will be read as a double.

Answer (score 1):

By using `Scanner::nextDouble` you are forcing the input to only be doubles, but if you were to use `Scanner::nextLine` then you could then try to convert to a double and if that fails then print the message

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter double");
 String line = scan.nextLine();

 double firstNum = 0.00;

 try {
    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(line);
 }
 catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("Not a double");
 }
```

Also, rather than doing

```
if (first>second) {
    System.out.println(first-second);
}
else if (second>first) {
    System.out.println(second-first);
}
```

it would be easier to do

```
System.out.println (Math.abs(first - second));
```

and also you should remove this line as it is not necessary and you are not even using it

```
Scanner scaning = new Scanner(System.in);
```